Terminated employee will not help the company locate its truck
Consider the following hypothetical situation. Joe is an employee of Quality trucking company. Joe drives a tractor trailer for the company. The tractor trailer is owned by
the company.
The company is unhappy with Joe as an employee. One day, while driving the company truck, Joe gets a phone call from his boss saying  that he is terminated immediately. Joe says "Okay" and  hangs  up the phone". He then legally parks the company truck and takes an uber home. The trailer has a significant amount of customer merchandise in it that Joe was delivering.
One hour later, Joe's boss calls him and asks Joe where the truck is. Joe does not answer the phone. The company does not know where the truck is. Can the company require Joe to tell them where the  truck is?

Does he leave the keys in the truck, or does he take them?

@jen I am asking what legal action could the company  take to help with the situation. That might be having  a court issue an order to Joe to tell the company where the  truck is.

@Greendrake Let say Joe takes the keys for the truck and he informs the  company, via email, that they can come by and pick then up from his apartment.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

united-states
Generally, the trucking company ought to have a fairly specific idea about where the truck is located and law enforcement might help them find an abandoned truck, based upon the planned itinerary of the truck and the time of the call. And, in real life, this issue does not come up because these kinds of trucks have GPS trackers (much to the distaste of the drivers who feel that they are micromanaged as a result). Often the freight customer will also have GPS tracking chips in their merchandise. The employer could simply dispatch some private individual to locate and retrieve it by searching along its anticipated route.
It is not obvious that Joe violates any legal duty by not responding to the employer's post-termination calls, especially one an hour later rather than mere moments later. Joe has no duty to his former employer to even keep a phone on his person. There isn't a general legal duty to respond to phone calls from anyone, including a former employer. Joe doesn't even know what the former employer was calling to ask. Joe had every right to block all calls from the employer's number once he was fired if he wanted to do so.
A judge or jury in later litigation might also have little sympathy for a company that unilaterally fires a trucker (without any cause identified in the question) and orders him to abandon the truck, in the middle of a trip, without asking where the truck is first, when Joe does what he was asked to do.
It is conceivable that if there was later litigation, that a subpoena could be issued to Joe to testify about where he left the truck, but that would take weeks, by which time it would be a moot point.
If law enforcement were notified of an abandoned truck and asked Joe about it, he might be obligated to tell them, in at least some states, but law enforcement might have a difficult time locating Joe promptly if he was not fired close to home.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

"orders him to abandon the truck" - the question doesn't say that - the very heart of the question is whether courts would interpret "you're fired" to imply immediately abandoning the truck (at the nearest legal parking spot), or whether they'd interpret it to mean ensuring the safe and timely return of the truck to the employer. Some additional possibilities that are worth noting/addressing in the answer: the employment contract making a provision for this or the employee being told to return the truck or finish the shift/delivery, or them hanging up (which actually the question states).

Are there any statutes or case law supporting the suggestion that terminated employees carry zero responsibility for the safe or timely return of company property? That seems like a rather counter-intuitive claim that's contrary to how I understand ownership and possession laws. What if the truck or merchandise was stolen or spoils? Would the same logic apply to e.g. a terminated employee abandoning a company laptop in a public space?

germany
Any company property the employee had in their possession is still company property. This is no different for laptops, cars or trucks.
The former employee owes the former employer a way to recover their property (§ 667 BGB). Normally, that is arranging pickup at the employee's home for a laptop, but being available for someone from the employer to pick up any movable goods (keys, papers) that are needed and telling them the location of their property if publicly accessible is enough. This assumes the property was left there for a good reason, not moved away out of spite.
Reasonable accommodations have to be made: you don't have to be available at weird hours for pickup, but telling someone the location of a truck can easily be a phone call or email, so compared to actual physical pickup one has to plan and arrange, there is no reason not to tell the former employer immediately.
It might even be a legal nightmare to actually drive the truck after officially being fired. So parking it at the nearest legal spot after being fired effectively immediate is the only appropriate action here.
If the company had wanted the truck returned, they should have fired the worker after they returned the truck or fired them with a notice period big enough that they can return the truck. "Your last day is Friday, please used the remaining days to return the truck to the logistics center in Citytown" would have been perfectly fine.
Please note that this is not a realistic scenario in Germany either way, because terminating an employee requires the notice to be in writing, just like the original contract. You cannot legally fire someone over the phone or via email. With all the EU regulations on digital signatures on contracts that might change for email, but phone does not produce a paper trail and will not be legally valid any time soon.

"it might even be a legal nightmare to actually drive the truck after officially being fired": this seems rather likely.  The decision to fire the driver in these circumstances without making arrangements for the truck is a very poor decision, and the employer will have to live with potentially significant negative consequences even if they know where the truck is.

@nvoigt what laws do you draw the conclusion in paragraph 2 from?

@Tom Assuming that a truck is for official business use and not also for private use, it would simply be "§ 667 BGB". It would be a little more complicated if it were a normal car and the employer had previously allowed private use and the termination is disputed in court. But I think this case is clear, the truck's use was purely business. This is a so-called https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holschuld, so the owner is entitled to their property, but not entitled to have it delivered to them. They need to get (holen) it themselves.

Agree. I've edited the answer to include that.

Whilst the specific circumstances of immediate firing are not viable due to the combination of written notification and formal notice period, that does allow for an even stupider scenario that could happen in a large organization: One part of the organization posts a written letter to Joe, starting the notice period, whilst another part ignorant or uninterested in the notice period, insists Joe keeps driving the truck such that the notice period ends whilst Joe is directed to be driving halfway between two locations.

@phoog do note that in Germany, immediate firing is very hard.

@phoog : another nightmare is if the trucker is fired while being far away from home, in a location with very poor or nonexistent public transport, making the trip back home very expensive and time-consuming. I wonder if the trucker could successfully sue for the costs of (and time spent) traveling home.

@vsz that'd be a great follow-up question.

@Trish In over 25 years in the Dutch workforce I've only seen people fired on the spot twice. In both cases it was due to serious misconduct (fraud, theft, things like that), and in both cases it was done in person in the presence of both the CEO and head of HR, certainly not over the phone (and in both cases lawyers were present as lawsuits were filed against the persons fired).

@infinitezero : https://law.stackexchange.com/q/105093/544

The ex-employee is in breach of their contract
australia
Some terms of a contract survive its termination and breach of these may be grounds for damages or the seeking of an injunction - in this case, ordering the employee to disclose the location of the truck.
While there may (perhaps should) be an explicit term requiring ex-employees to return company property, it’s not strictly necessary.
At common law, employees owe a duty of fidelity to their employer and this continues after termination to the extent that it relates to their employment. Failing to tell the employer where the truck is is a breach of this duty.

The common law case law in many U.S. jurisdictions sharply delineates between the pre-termination and post-termination period. See, e.g. https://law.justia.com/cases/colorado/supreme-court/1989/87sc182-0.html

united-kingdom
I think this falls into the category of "involuntary bailment".
Rather than considering exactly what the former employee must do, it's more appropriate firstly to consider what they mustn't do: they mustn't abandon or recklessly endanger the vehicle in their possession.
So the vehicle remains under their control.
And because the vehicle is under their control, they must return the vehicle on demand, or endeavour to return the vehicle to the owner. To not do so could be theft.
In the absence of the employment relationship, the efforts the former employee must take are not onerous (for example, there is no obligation to drive the truck on from an already sensible parking place) and are not determined by how urgently the former employer would wish to recover the vehicle, but wilful obstruction of the employer's efforts, or knowingly allowing a perishable load to perish whilst delaying contact, may be unlawful.

In the UK it's illegal to drive without insurance. If his employer has a policy covering employees, and he's no longer employed, does he cease to be insured to drive?

This assumes that the after being fired immediately that the employee even has the authority operate the vehicle. No cause is listed, but suppose that the urgent action to fire him was, for example, because the company just learned that his driver's license had been revoked for drunk driving in his private life. He parked it legally (and presumably kept the doors locked when he left it, and the company probably has a spare key anyway). This seems like it is reasonable as opposed to reckless endangerment. They basically told him to stop driving immediately, so how is that theft?

@ohwilleke, but the question didn't specify that they told him to stop driving immediately.  Nor did it state the reason for termination.  Each answer must make certain presumptions, and Steve has stated his.

@ohwilleke, it's not theft to comply with specific directions of the owner. The issue is whether the former employee can just treat the vehicle in their charge as abandoned in a public place due to the termination of their employment, assuming they are not directed to abandon it. The law may say he cannot actually drive the vehicle, that does not then mean he isn't under an obligation to make arrangements for its movement or return.

How could it be a theft? Theft presumes that there's an intention to take possession of a property, which is the opposite of what's happening.
